# running a dos command via java as administrator

Tags: java, dos

I have a dos command which starts an application. I want to start the application as an administrator. How can i do so? Below is the code which i tried.

```
String arg[]={"C:\\app1.exe", "C:\\app2.exe", "c:\\app3.exe"};
String pwd[]={"123","-x","-sf"};
String outputfile="c:\\output.xml"
String command=arg[0]+pwd[0]+arg[1]+pwd[1]+arg[2]+pwd[3]+output;
Process pr=rt.exec(command);
```

I tried the same command from command prompt and its working fine. But when i try to run the same from java code, it keeps on running without producing any output.

Comment: I'm not sure, but in order to do this without tapping into the Windows API, you will probably have to run your Java program with elevation. Then anything the program does will have elevation as well.

Answer (score 2):

see runas -command:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: i tried using runas but application ".exe " is not starting if i give runas. I gave runas /user:macname\\admin.

Comment: Have you tried it with the `/env` parameter in `runas` right from the command prompt before you try it from java `exec()`? If you don't put `/env`, runas will assume that you want it run using the environment variables set in the user profile of `/user` parameter rather than the  environment variables set from the current user/process

Comment: If my suggestion above still doesn't work, then you have no choice but to elevate your app's privilege to the highest possible privilege as suggested by nalroff (such as `run as administrator` or set the security level for your Java app using Windows `.manifest` file) so that anything you call from `exec()` will inherit the same privilege as your app